# secure of phoenix Plug.Session set value on runtime

Tags: web, elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to set value of secure on runtime.
But it is set value on compile time.
I don’t know how to do that.
My env is elixir 12, erlang 24
Plz help me

```elixir
plug Plug.Session,
    store: :cookie,
    key: "_key",
    signing_salt: "KahwH24",
    max_age: 60 * 60,
    secure: System.get_env("PLUG_SESSION_SECURE", "true") == "true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are facing the issue on your production environment.

If you are using [Elixir releases](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/releases.html#content) and Phoenix 1.6 for deployment, you can place this code inside `config/runtime.exs`. Phoenix picks up these configurations at runtime.

If you are using [Distillery](https://hexdocs.pm/distillery/home.html), you can use [config providers](https://hexdocs.pm/distillery/config/runtime.html#config-providers) which help configure the app at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

With a few exceptions, it turns out that most things in an Elixir app can be configured during runtime.  The secret is to use the `config/runtime.exs` file.  I have found that using ONLY the `config/config.exs` for compile-time configurations and `config/runtime.exs` for runtime configurations aligns better with how I think about my code and its environment, and it fits in nicely with the recommendations of [the 12-Factor App](https://12factor.net/)

See article re runtime [Configuration in Elixir using Dotenvy](https://fireproofsocks.medium.com/configuration-in-elixir-with-dotenvy-8b20f227fc0e)